# Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\foo as array

Tags: php, arrays, orm, symfony-2.3

Maybe it look basic, i forget or missing something? when  i did this

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public $mSelectedDepartment =0;
   public  $mDepartment;


    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $mSelectedDepartment=$this->getSelectedDepartment();
         $departments=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:departments')->findAll();


        //create department links
        for($i=0;$i<count($departments);$i++)
        {
            //generate simple link exp 'index?DepartmentId/1 '
          $this->mDepartment[$i]['link_to_department']='index/DepartmentId/=';  // my point is to fench [department_id]


        }
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [ 'department'=>$departments,'selectedDepartment'=>$mSelectedDepartment
        ]);


    }

  function getSelectedDepartment()
  {
      return $this->mSelectedDepartment;
  }




}
```

And then dump the variable `dump($departments[$i])`, it shows me

```
 departments {#528 ▼
  -department_id: 1
  -name: "Regional"
  -discription: "Proud of your country? Wear a T-shirt with a national symbol stamp!"
}
```

In DefaultController.php line 31:

```
departments {#526 ▼
  -department_id: 2
  -name: "Nature"
  -discription: "Find beautiful T-shirts with animals and flowers in our Nature department!"
}
```

In DefaultController.php line 31:

```
departments {#525 ▼
  -department_id: 3
  -name: "Seasonal"
  -discription: "Each time of the year has a special flavor. Our seasonal T-shirts express traditional symbols using unique postal stamp pictures."
}
```

So i assume it was array. But why when i try to  access

```
dump($departments[$i]['department_id ']);
```

it says:

> Cannot use object of type departments as array

Comment: So you assumption is __wrong__ and you have an object, not array.

Comment: any idea how make it work

Comment: Open `department` model and see what getters and setters are there.

Answer (score 1):

You have an object and not an array so you have to do something like this

```
foreach ($departments as $department){
$my_department=(array) $department;
print_r($my_department);
}
```

Comment: Using doctrine properly there's as likely hood that department_id is private/protected so it'll likely be ->getDepartmentId()

Comment: Yes it is better according to the department-id definition with in the class I can not guess here if it is public or private

Comment: foreach ($departments as $department)       {           echo " $departments->department_id";       }  now it say Notice: Trying to get property of non-object wonder why

Comment: Try to echo gettype($department);

Comment: echo gettype($departments);  it say array

Comment: I edit the code above I think you have object of array so you loop through the $departments as object then you treat with each $department as array

Comment: foreach ($departments as $department)
    {
        echo $department['department_id'];
    }   it back to Cannot use object of type AppBundle\Entity\departments as array

Comment: Try to print_r it

Answer (score 0):

thanks after  keep trying  i realize that  the department _id properties is private so i change to public

> Array ( [0] => AppBundle\Entity\departments Object (
>   [department_id:AppBundle\Entity\departments:private] => 1
>   [name:AppBundle\Entity\departments:private] => Regional
>   [discription:AppBundle\Entity\departments:private] => Proud of your
>   country? Wear a T-shirt with a national symbol stamp! ) [1] =>
>   AppBundle\Entity\departments Object (
>   [department_id:AppBundle\Entity\departments:private] => 2
>   [name:AppBundle\Entity\departments:private] => Nature
>   [discription:AppBundle\Entity\departments:private] => Find beautiful
>   T-shirts with animals and flowers in our Nature department! ) [2] =>
>   AppBundle\Entity\departments Object (
>   [department_id:AppBundle\Entity\departments:private] => 3
>   [name:AppBundle\Entity\departments:private] => Seasonal
>   [discription:AppBundle\Entity\departments:private] => Each time of the
>   year has a special flavor. Our seasonal T-shirts express traditional
>   symbols using unique postal stamp pictures. ) )

it fix as i want by

```
   //generate simple link exp 'index?DepartmentId/1 '
          $this->mDepartment[$i]['link_to_department']='index/DepartmentId/'.$departments[$i]->department_id;
```

> and now new question is it save to use public properties at entity
>   class properties before that thanks guys for support

```
    array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "link_to_department" => "index/DepartmentId/1"
  ]
]
In DefaultController.php line 32:
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "link_to_department" => "index/DepartmentId/1"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "link_to_department" => "index/DepartmentId/2"
  ]
]
In DefaultController.php line 32:
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "link_to_department" => "index/DepartmentId/1"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "link_to_department" => "index/DepartmentId/2"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
    "link_to_department" => "index/DepartmentId/3"
```